# Событие при вводе текста в TINYMCE

Tags: jquery, события, tinymce, javascript

Нужно как-то перехватить событие при вводе текста в форму tinymce и когда ввод происходит - выполнить функцию. Это для того, чтобы активировать кнопку "Сохранить изменения" только после того, как эти изменения произойдут. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, вот что [предлагается на офф.сайте](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/setup_editor_events.php) по работе с событиями.
Из их примеров - при инициализации добавляем свои настройки:

```
tinyMCE.init({
// в начале все по стандарту (ваша конфигурация)
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "mybutton,bold,italic,underline,separator,strikethrough,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,undo,redo,link,unlink",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    plugins : 'inlinepopups',
// Вот то, что нам и надо !!!
// begin
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onClick.add(function(ed) {
            ed.windowManager.alert('Юзер кликнул в поле редактора.');
        });
    }
// end
});
```